# what is the purpose of this & symbol in this context?

Tags: java

```
public class WeatherAggregator {
    private List&lt;WeatherSource&gt; weatherSources;

    public WeatherAggregator(List&lt;WeatherSource&gt; weatherSources) {
        this.weatherSources = weatherSources;
    }

    public double getTemperature() {
        return weatherSources
            .stream()
            .mapToDouble(WeatherSource::getTemperatureCelcius)
            .average()
            .getAsDouble();
    }
}
```

I searched about what does the & symbol here mean but I could not find any meaning to it ?! 
can you tell what is going on in this line ?

```
private List&lt;WeatherSource&gt;weatherSources;
```

Comment: I found this code on the internet by the way in a DIP principle tutorial

Comment: It means you accidentally picked up some HTML in your source.  That should say `List<WeatherSource>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! you solved my issue but if you have time please consider telling what exactly is " HTML was picked " because i am a bit curious ! 
Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just HTML source encoding of the `<` and `>`. The following:

```
List&lt;WeatherSource&gt;
```

is actually

```
List<WeatherSource>
```

See here for the [HTML escape characters](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php)